# Is 64 bit RTC and high resolution performance counter same?

Tags: winapi

Is high resolution performance counter and 64 bit RTC both works based on number of CPU Cycles since the system started? Both uses same hardware?

Jit

Comment: Very good question. +1 - hoping for an authoritative answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is up to the motherboard + BIOS, the HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer) picks it up.  But it wasn't traditionally and it certainly isn't these days with variable cpu clock rates.  The motherboard builder usually picks a frequency available in the chipset.  The traditional rate was 1.1932 MHz, the [NTSC color burst frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTSC#Color_encoding) divided by 3 and the clock source of the Intel 8253 timer chip.  But no longer around anymore due to relentless cost cutting.

Always use QueryPerformanceFrequency().